# spring integration PayloadTypeRouter with javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement

Tags: routes, spring-integration, jaxb2, payload

whats the best routing solution for payload type routing based on a javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement? Here is the current configuration I have.

```
<oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="wsMarshaller" contextPath="com.test.conn.ws.domain"/>

<int:channel id="jaxbInputChannel" />

<int-ws:inbound-gateway id="wsInboundMarsellingGateway"
    request-channel="jaxbInputChannel" marshaller="wsMarshaller" unmarshaller="wsMarshaller" />

<int:service-activator input-channel="jaxbInputChannel">
<bean class="com.test.conn.application.AImpl" />
```

```
<int:service-activator input-channel="jaxbInputChannel">
<bean class="com.test.conn.application.BImpl" />
```

The payload types received in AImpl and BImpl are javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement and javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement. But when i use soapUI to invoke B request, it invokes AImpl. More service activators there is (for different payload types), more confusion there is on which service activator to invoke.

So decided to resolve this by adding a **PayloadTypeRouter**, but then the question comes on how to define this for type **javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement, javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement** etc.

I'm hoping there's an easy solution using SpEL (or another straight forward way) rather than adding a transformer in front to get hold of the request getValue.. Any advise will help immensely.

thanks.

---

As mentioned in the earlier post i went ahead with PayloadTypeRouter, transformer implementation. There i hit another road block.

```
<int:transformer input-channel="jaxbInputChannel" output-channel="jaxbRoutingChannel"  >
    <bean class="com.test.conn.transformer.ConnTransformer" />
</int:transformer>

<int:payload-type-router input-channel="jaxbRoutingChannel"  >
    <int:mapping type="com.test.conn.ws.domain.A" channel="aInputChannel" />
    <int:mapping type="com.test.conn.ws.domain.B" channel="bInputChannel" />
</int:payload-type-router>
```

Here is the error message i get.

> Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E:(pos 8): Method call: Method test(com.test.conn.ws.domain.A) cannot be found on com.sun.proxy.$Proxy40 type

I'm puzzled. Why would spring be looking at the service activator method in com.test.conn.ws.domain.A instance?

Comment: Why is payload type coming out of the adapter a JAXBElement? I am guessing it's a JAXB configuration problem; the unmarshaller should be unmarshalling to an `A` or a `B` not a JAXBElement. Is your transformer now doing that? I suggest you turn on debug logging; if you can't figure it out from that, post the log including the full stack trace.

Comment: We use design tool (EA) to generate the xsd from class diagram. The JAXB2 generated code based on this xsd is as JAXBElement<T>. I'm relatively new to the project and team has being doing this without any issues. Just to figure out if there were any issues with approach debug option was enabled but didn't come across any complains on this.

Comment: For the 'SpelEvaluationException: EL1004E:(pos 8)' problem.. i realized it was an AOP issue and added an interfaces on service activators to fix it. Also went with a <int:header-enricher with expression="payload.getDeclaredType().getSimpleName()" and then <int:header-value-router. Figured this would be more cleaner than adding a custom transformer. Thanks for quickly responding Gary :)